# Apigee Edge Private Cloud 4.16.09 Baffling Installation Error

Tags: nginx, apigee

During installation of Apigee Edge Private Cloud version 4.16.09 (i.e. the latest version), I'm running into a frustrating error in the Router/Message-proc (RMP) installation. **Specifically, with the apigee-ngnix package.** Before I get into the details, here is some basic info about the machine on which the installation is taking place:

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo)
# uname -a
Linux *** 3.10.0-327.18.2.el7.x86_64 *** Fri Apr 8 05:09:53 EDT 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The command to issue the RMP install is the following:

```
/opt/apigee/apigee-setup/bin/setup.sh -p rmp -f /tmp/myConfig.txt
```

And the subsequent output (containing the error in question) is as follows:

```
apigee-service: edge-router: edge-router is running

Checking for router on 127.0.0.1 port 8081 ............. OK

Checking for router uuid 649f58ba-bb61-469e-b169-ceb955961242

Checking if router is up .............................................................

router is not up.

Error: setup.sh: /opt/apigee/apigee-service/bin/apigee-service exited with unexpected status 1
```

When I dig into the logs, I see the following errors-

/opt/apigee/var/log/edge-router/edge-router.log:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/opt/nginx/scripts/apigee-nginx": error=2, No such file or directory

at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
```

Very bizarre that the apigee-ngnix file is not being created by the installation process (as it should).

/opt/apigee/var/log/edge-router/logs/system.log:

```
2017-01-05 13:11:09,012 main-EventThread ERROR o.a.c.ConnectionState - ConnectionState.checkState() : Authentication failed

...

2017-01-06 11:18:55,249 qtp371397455-42 ERROR REST - CustomJAXRSInvoker.performInvocation() : CustomJAXRSInvoker.performInvocation : Method com.apigee.registration.ServersAPI.isServerCompletelyUp threw an exception.

...

2017-01-06 11:18:55,253 qtp371397455-42 ERROR REST - ExceptionMapper.toResponse() : Error occurred : Service not up yet.

com.apigee.registration.ServersAPI.isServerCompletelyUp(ServersAPI.java:106)

sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

2017-01-06 11:18:55,255 qtp371397455-42 ERROR REST - ExceptionMapper.toResponse() : Returning error response : ErrorResponse{errorCode = null, errorMessage = Service not up yet.}

...

2017-01-06 11:18:55,576 main ERROR LOAD-BALANCER - LoadBalancingManagementServiceImpl.start() : Could not Initialize adaptor nginx

...

2017-01-06 11:18:55,603 main ERROR Router-Service - RouterServiceImpl.start() : Router not started because, Load Balancing could not be initialized

2017-01-06 11:18:55,614 main ERROR KERNEL.DEPLOYMENT - ServiceDeployer.startService() : ServiceDeployer.deploy() : Got a life cycle exception while starting service [RouterService, Nginx Initialization failed] : {}

com.apigee.errors.http.server.ServiceFailureException: Nginx Initialization failed

at com.apigee.proxy.service.RouterServiceImpl.start(RouterServiceImpl.java:65) ~[message-router-proxy-1.0.0.jar:na]
```

I'm quite baffled how this could be happening. I don't see any other errors in the various log files. Any ideas of what could be awry here? Perhaps where to look for other clues and/or how to proceed in the installation? I've tried opening up the permission settings beyond what should be necessary in the folder structure around nginx (just to be safe), but to no avail.

Note that the installation for all the other components in the Apigee Edge install (e.g. management server, analytics, datastore, etc) works without even the slightest issue!

Thanks in advance for any and all help or insight!

Best,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directly before installing the router and message processor component, run the below commands, which are a viable workaround for this issue:

```
mkdir /opt/apigee/etc/edge-router.d
echo RUN_USER=root >> /opt/apigee/etc/edge-router.d/RUN_USER.sh
chown -R apigee:apigee /opt/apigee/etc/edge-router.d
```

​
Best,
Chris